# Use PHP to get SQL data for various IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a table on my website which I have in my SQL database and I need each row of my table to get certain information from the columns. I have something that works just fine at the moment, however, I have a feeling its not the best way of doing things. As I have around 600+ rows in my database.

I'm trying to learn more about all of this so if you have any idea to do this in a better way then that would be fantastic.

```
<?php
    $queryContent="SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE id= 104";
    $resultContent= $mysqli->query($queryContent);
    $rowContent = $resultContent->fetch_assoc();
?>
<?php if ($rowContent['active'] == "Y") { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rowContent['businessname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowContent['telephoneno']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowContent['emailaddress']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowContent['rating']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why do you feel this is not the best way of doing things?

Comment: And .... What's the problem???

Comment: If your issue is that all 600 rows are loading on one page, i'd look into setting up pagination so that you can limit the results shown per page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to list all active rows, try something like this:

```
<?php
    // Change query to select only acitve rows
    $queryContent="SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE active = 'Y'";
    $resultContent= $mysqli->query($queryContent);

    //while cycle will repeat while sql have results
    while($rowContent = $resultContent->fetch_assoc()){ 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rowContent['businessname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowContent['telephoneno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowContent['emailaddress']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowContent['rating']; ?></td>
</tr><?php } ?>
```

[Php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1951) examples should be also usefull.

When you have a list of IDs wich you want to select from sql look at [SQL WHERE - IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator and syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE id IN (103, 104, 105)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two things which can be improved in your code:

1. instead of select *, you can mention select column1, column2,... which is considered to be the standard
2. And if you are trying to list only one row, then either access the $rowcontent array with index 0 (or) limit the select query's output rows by using "LIMIT 1" at the end of "SELECT" query (second option valid only if you are not sure about the query whether it will fetch only one row always or not)